are all french presses the same?
Lots of online discussion suggests that there isn't much differentiating french presses / cafetières.
So I'm asking here - what are the key differentiators amongst french presses?
My inexpert view is the following:

all-metal vs glass which breaks
double-walled vs not for improved heat retention

Is that it?

The ones you listed are important, because they will depend on your specific use case. But there’s a large percentage of personal preference, for example I would choose the glass over metal (aesthetics, cleaning, allows to use visual clues in addition to time) and non-insulated (because I never leave the coffee standing on the grounds for a prolonged time).
But there’s one element that you didn’t mention but that is in my opinion even more important:
The mesh and its properties.

It should fit snugly to the walls of the container, or you may have grounds “escaping” at the sides.
It should be the right mesh size to neither clog up nor let too much dust pass - which will of course also means you need the right grind settings.
It’s good to check how well you can dismantle the filter part, because you will at some point want to take it apart for a deep cleaning.
And finally, it must be stainless steel in all metal parts. I am emphasizing this because I have seen coated screens where the top layer got rubbed off and non-stainless screws and nuts, both started to rust.

These are factors that can seriously spoil your enjoyment of a French Press. Read the reviews carefully before buying, users will typically mention these if something is amiss.

Good point about the mesh. I’d add that double wall or insulated will stabilize brewing temperature - making more consistent brews - even if you decant the coffee after. And to note two unique designs, the Espro P3 seals the grounds off from the coffee after plunging. And the aero press, which is not exactly a French press but is practically.

Another variable is the type of "glass" the container is made of. Most are actually glass, but Pyrex (borosilicate glass) is much preferable. It is much more durable and heat resistant.
By coincidence, the standard 1 liter French Press is the same dimensions as a "tall form" Pyrex laboratory beaker. They are available from Amazon for only a bit more $ than replacement "glass" French Press containers.
For the boat, I have a Nissan Stainless Steel vacuum French Press. It keeps coffee hot for hours and is nearly indestructible. Unfortunately, the innards don't float and have needed to be replaced when they went overboard with the grounds. But the industry seems to make these things standard dimensions and it was easy to replace.
